# Core Data crashes when delete managed object

Tags: core-data, ios5

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  
This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  
-[__NSCFSet removeObject:]: attempt to remove nil with userInfo (null)
        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet removeObject:]: attempt to remove nil'
```

Application crashes on save context operation. (The case is: I perform segue in tableView, enter but even not modifying anything in destinationViewController, and when I'm and delete row in tableView app crashes.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error2 %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            abort();
        }
```

Comment: BTW: Deleted all database, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Not enough info to go on. That debugger dump is to generic. Are you using threads? Do you have more than one context or the same context on two different threads? The code higher up in the stack will tell us more.

Comment: Please see now — I corrected the post

Comment: Please symbolicate the call stack, with a human readable call stack it might be possible to locate the problem

Comment: Can you provide the code where you re deleting the managedObject subclass as well as where you might be monitoring the notification?

Comment: timthetoolman, I delete managedObject in tableView
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:

Answer (score 1):

Dima,

Chances are you are trying to delete a class with a required parameter. Double check your model or code to meet your entities requirements. If my hypothesis is correct, you just need to make the relationship optional.

Andrew

Comment: Unfortunately no.
I see that the problem comes up when I delete row in my tableview — only if I visited before next ViewController by segue.